# Present running total in a table column

Tags: tableau-api

I'm building a simple table to display event bookings, grouped by date, in descending date order so that when the report is refreshed, the latest totals are displayed at the top of the table.

I want to present a running total alongside the daily counts. I've copied the measure and tried to use the 'Running Total' quick table calculation, but it only allows you to run the calculation down the table: "Table (Down)".

I want to do the opposite of this, so the current running total appears at the top of the table alongside the most current date.

How can I make the Running Total - effectively - calculate up the table i.e. "Table (Up)"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you edit the field's table calculation, you want to select 'Advanced' under the "Running along" dropdown.

A popup appears and at the bottom is a section that allows you to define the sort. Check 'Field' and select your date field. Use 'Minimum' and then check 'Descending'.

[image]